# directory does not exist or could not be selected

Tags: php, file, localhost, hosting

So I made a website in xampp on localhost and everything worked but when i uploaded it to hostinger user gets http error 500 when trying to upload photo. However data gets to database and it shows up on website. Also in file manager I can see the directory where photos should be but if i try to enter it i get `The directory /public_html/path-to-dir does not exist or could not be selected, so the directory / is shown instead.`
 Can I get any suggestions what could be wrong? This is my first website i worked on so please don't go hard on me

Comment: This might be the file permissions issue, so please check proper permissions

Comment: Like he said ^^

Comment: Would you please tell me where those permissions are set? Is it on hosting or coding?

Answer (score 0):

For your 500, you can try to catch the fatal errors and see what is wrong.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); //E_ALL
function cache_shutdown_error() {
    $_error = error_get_last();
    if ($_error && in_array($_error['type'], array(1, 4, 16, 64, 256, 4096, E_ALL))) {
        echo '<font color=red>500 Error Caught</font></br>';
        echo 'Fatal error:' . $_error['message'] . '</br>';
        echo 'File: ' . $_error['file'] . '</br>';
        echo 'Line ' . $_error['line'] . '</br>';
    }
}

register_shutdown_function("cache_shutdown_error");
```

Also, if the permission is denied, you can find the file is either `644` or `600`. Also, check the user that the httpd is running at.

Comment: Ok, I found that when user uploads files the permissions on directory is set to r----x--t even though i specify 777 in php, so user can't see image in content